# Connecting Windows 10 to Linux Mint 21.2 over ethernet cable to use samba shares

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, samba, crossover-cable

I'm trying to set up a small home NAS with Linux Mint 21.2 to access samba shares from Windows 10 laptops using a direct cable connection. I've assigned IP 10.10.91.5 to the laptop ethernet card, and 10.10.91.6 to the linux ethernet interface. Laptop has Gigabit card and linux box has 10/100 card. Default gateway for connections in both machines point to each other. Machines can ping each other just fine. I added 'interfaces = 10.10.91.6' to [global] section in /etc/samba/smb.conf . Did try both straight trough and crossover cables to no avail.

Machines can ping each other just fine, but 'net view 10.10.91.6' in Win10 machines always return 'System Error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found'. Using just 'net view' sees a laptop share but doesn't detect linux host or shares.

Any advise greatly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues.

### Physical network connection

To connect several PCs you need either direct cable or a switch. Straight or crossover cables was the problem when you had two of 10/100 MBit network cards. If at least one card is Gigabit, the card will do "crossover" for you automatically, i.e. it will work anyway, you don't have to worry.

### IP addresses

As long as the two addresses are different and belong to the same subnet (which is defined by the subnet mask, for IP 10.*.*.* it is probably 255.0.0.0), you do not need even a default gateway. **If ping works, it's totally fine.**

### Samba configuration

This is where it all begins. You have to get samba server running, quite good and simple description is here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/samba-file-server
At the beginning, I would not set 'interfaces' in the [global] section. Create some share on the Linux machine. Create samba users with `smbpasswd`, these have different password database from the system users.

Make sure the share works from the Linux box with `smbclient`.

### Access from Windows

In the windows explorer address bar, enter `\\10.10.91.6\sharename` and press Enter.

That's for the beginning.